# generating random time entries before and after midnight Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to generate random time entries between two time limits in Excel. the problem i am facing is the generation works fine with the same day time calculation as soon as the time passes midnight, Excel gets confused and give me wrong values values. I need to generate random entries then match it to the closest value it has in the time series given in the sample workbook. Can anyone help me?

[Workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArYn8TW3_a3d32oXZtCJ9Bd364vO)

Comment: Are you doing this in vba? (I didn't open the workbook file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
=IF(ROWS($D$10:$D10)>$F$4,"",IF(HOUR($C$4)<HOUR($C$5),TIME(RANDBETWEEN(HOUR($C$4),HOUR($C$5)-1),INDEX({0,15,30,45},RANDBETWEEN(1,4)),0),IF(HOUR($C$4)=HOUR($C$5),TIME(HOUR($C$4),INDEX({0,15,30,45},RANDBETWEEN(1,4)),0),IF(HOUR($C$4)>HOUR($C$5),TIME(IF(RANDBETWEEN(0,1)=1,RANDBETWEEN(HOUR($C$4),23),RANDBETWEEN(0,HOUR($C$5)-1)),INDEX({0,15,30,45},RANDBETWEEN(1,4)),0),1))))
```

Hope you can share the results.. (It'll benefit others too) (:

Comment: Thankyou it works. but i found another way to do it by making just a small change at the end. by replacing `-- ,$C$4+RAND()*($C$5-$C$4))` with `--MOD($C$4+RAND()*($C$5-$C$4+($C$5 < $C$4)),1)` . Thank you for your help. really appreciate it

Comment: Glad it helps. ( :